# Is it possible to use expo-google-sign-in with android emulator (Expo client)

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-signin

I am developing an application with expo. I need the user to be authenticated through google. So I wanted to use : [expo-google-sign-in](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/)
Reading expo documentation I see :

> It cannot be used in the Expo client

And just below I see:

> Platform Compatibility : Android Emulator OK

This is very confusing because when using expo you launch the Emulator/Simulator. And it is written first this library can NOT be used within Emulator and then that it can.
**Is it because when "expo team" says Android Emulator OK they mean launching Emulator from android studio ? What is the correct workflow of dev to use expo-google-sign-in ? Please "expo team" any reactions because I see so many expo users confused about google sign in.**

Answer (score 0):

`expo-google-sign-in` cannot be used in the Expo client as the native `GoogleSignIn` library expects your `REVERSE_CLIENT_ID` in the `info.plist` at build-time.

Therefore the Expo team suggests using [`expo-google-app-auth`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/) instead if you want to test using the Expo client. This authentication method authenticates the user through a secure web browser window.

However, if you are insistent on using `expo-google-sign-in` you need to build the .apk and either drag it into your physical device or use an Android emulator.

Comment: I would like to use any solution that allow me to test my app. But from what I understand it would be implemented differently between dev and apk, so that's a weird situation. And by the way I see that expo-google-app-auth is not ready : https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9522

Comment: The implementation between dev and apk should be similar, worst case test it out real quick. The issue you linked has been marked as closed and resolved however.

Comment: The issue I linked suggests to use android 11 which I find does not solve the problem but swipe out dust under the carpet. By the way Evan Bacon suggests (https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5615) to use expo-app-auth instead. That's such a mess. Redseb have you implemented a working sign in with google in a react native / expo app ?

Comment: Not yet in production apps to be fair... Try `expo-app-auth`?